# How to change column name in mysql if column name has space?

Tags: mysql

```
ALTER TABLE studentrecord CHANGE COLUMN  Full name fullname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL;
```

I just want to change 'Full name' to 'Fullname'

Answer (score 5):

Enclose the field name in back-ticks like this:

```
ALTER TABLE studentrecord CHANGE COLUMN `Full name` Fullname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL;
```